# Create a list from a DataFrame to use a for function in Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, graph

Hi I'm trying to add value labels to a graph and I have this dataset:

I'm using this code to generate the graph for the diferent columns:

```
ax = dfu.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(14, 10), xlabel='Number of Employees in Company', ylabel='Count', rot=0)
ax.legend(title='treatment', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')

rects = ax.patches

# Make some labels.
labels = [f"{i}" for i in dfu]

for rect, label in zip(rects, labels):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(
        rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height + 2, label, ha="center", va="bottom"
    )
```

My main problem is that the code is taking the column name as text labels for the columns but I want to generate a list to obtain this labels and for the moment I have a for:

But is not saving all the values in one list some help here please:
(At the end is the graph)

```
for o in dfu.columns:
    col_one_arr = dfu[o]
    print(col_one_arr)
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data. This is hard to copy'n'past. If you have a pandas DataFrame, you can use `print(df.to_string())` to get a nice print of your data. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73805855/edit) your post.

Comment: @mosc9575 so how I copy data? and that didn't work

Comment: Please reas [how to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) your post. I suggest to copy'n'past your DataFrame and put it in a code section. Please also tag your question with `python` to automaticlly use the python code highlightning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ax = dfu.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(14, 10), xlabel='Number of Employees in Company', ylabel='Count', rot=0)
ax.legend(title='treatment', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')

rects = ax.patches

# Make some labels.
liv = []
for o in dfu.columns:
    dfv = dfu[o].values
    liv.extend(dfv)
    #print(dfv)

labels = [f"{i}" for i in liv]

for rect, label in zip(rects, labels):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(
        rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height + 2, label, ha="center", va="bottom"
    )
```